# Drive detection only detecting one drive?

Tags: java, detection, drive

Hello all I am using `if (canRead && canWrite && !isFloppy && isDrive)` and it only will read off the first drive it finds "C:\", I have a HDD and a SSD, it wont detect the ssd for somereason "D:\" for some reason anyehelp? Thanks.

Sorry guys slipped my mind to include the vars:

```
package javaapplication3;

import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

class filler
{
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws InterruptedException
    { 
        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
        File[] f = File.listRoots();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
            String drive = f[i].getPath();
            String displayName = fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f[i]);
            String type = fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(f[i]);
            boolean isDrive = fsv.isDrive(f[i]);
            boolean isFloppy = fsv.isFloppyDrive(f[i]);
            boolean canRead = f[i].canRead();
            boolean canWrite = f[i].canWrite();
            //(type.toLowerCase().contains("removable") || type.toLowerCase().contains("rimovibile"))
            if (canRead && canWrite && !isFloppy && isDrive) {
                try {

                      File file = new File(drive +"log_22_2112321321312.log");

                      if (file.createNewFile()){
                          System.out.println("File is created!");
                      }
                      if (file.exists()){
                          System.out.println("Drive found " + drive);
                          file.delete();
                      }    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (canRead && canWrite && !isFloppy && isDrive &&(type.toLowerCase().contains("removable") || type.toLowerCase().contains("rimovibile"))) {
                try {

                    File file = new File("log_22_2112321321312.log");

                    if (file.createNewFile()){
                        System.out.println("File is created!");
                    }
                    if (file.exists()){
                        System.out.println("Drive found " + drive);
                        file.delete();
                    }    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you determine `canRead`, `canWrite`, `isFloppy` and `isDrive`??

Comment: Those are variables he must have created. Possible source: http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/506/Detect-USB-removable-drive-in-Java

Comment: Good find xD exact source Plus added them in the in the post

Comment: How do you know if your device isn't being detected without any output statements inside the loop?

Comment: I made it make a file for testing along with the output and it only makes a shortcut to teh file

Comment: You create the file with `new File()`, but immediately delete it afterwards with `file.delete()`. Can you provide the output of the program to see if it recognizes your D: drive?

Comment: output of program `Drive found C:\
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `File.listRoots()`? Check the output of the following:

```
File[] roots = File.listRoots();
for (File r : roots)
    System.out.println(r);
```

It's possible that your SSD is being detected but isn't passing your conditional's criteria. Code inside your conditional will only be executed if the specified condition is met. Run your code without the condition to see if the drive isn't actually being recognized, or whether it's not appearing due to a logic error or some other volume setting.

Comment: Shoudl have mentioned this I have all this `FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
        File[] f = File.listRoots();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        String drive = f[i].getPath();
        String displayName = fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f[i]);
        String type = fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(f[i]);
        boolean isDrive = fsv.isDrive(f[i]);
        boolean isFloppy = fsv.isFloppyDrive(f[i]);
        boolean canRead = f[i].canRead();
        boolean canWrite = f[i].canWrite();`

Comment: Please edit your original post to include that code, and format it as code. Add `System.out.println(f[i].getPath())` to see if it detects your device. Your conditional statement may be omitting it.